# Function in Android Studio programs worked fine before, but then this problem shows up

Tags: android

I tried to check all the code I write, edit some of it and some are fixed, but this problem still unfixed.
i expect the program could run

```
Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@796f578a.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@7d50cc7f.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@38525db1.,Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@af0056b.
```

```java
package com.example.inorasmart;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

}
```

Comment: Add your code so we could help you.

Comment: @ElazarHalperin where do i have to send the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@ef79973](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73558372/can-not-extract-resource-from-com-android-aaptcompiler-parsedresourceef79973)